# SQL About the output

Tags: sql, database

Why the output would be three people and how can it compere A.MID and B.MID with the same table? Ummmm... Maybe  explain how it works in detail. Thank you.

| MID | MNAME |
| --- | --- |
| 30005 | Alice Li |
| 20060 | Ben Hung |
| 30110 | Clara Ng |
| 20088 | Greg Chan |
| 10001 | Rita Lam |
| 40001 | Tim lee |
| 40002 | Yan Chan |

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.MNAME 
FROM MEM A
WHERE 2 >= (SELECT COUNT (*)
            FROM MEM B 
            WHERE A.MID > B.MID) ;
```

The answer:

```
Ben Hung
Greg Chan
Rita Lam
```

Comment: Please provide enough information. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get the specified answer, and the query is your non-working attempt? Or are you asking why the given query returns the specified answer? (It doesn't.)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/985EErFw, the above query and tinazmu's query.

Answer (score 0):

Reorganise like this, and you will see:

```
SELECT  A.MID, A.MNAME, (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM MEM B WHERE A.MID > B.MID) as CNT
FROM MEM A 
order by A.MID
```

| MID | MNAME | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Rita Lam | 0 |
| 20060 | Ben Hung | 1 |
| 20088 | Greg Chan | 2 |
| 30005 | Alice Li | 3 |
| 30110 | Clara Ng | 4 |
| 40001 | Tim lee | 5 |
| 40002 | Yan Chan | 6 |

Which ones have fewer than 3 entries with a smaller MID (that is what your query is asking for)? the first three!

The DISTINCT keyword plays no role, because all your MNAMEs are already unique.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh, I have made a small change, now it should work with most DBMS products

Comment: Yes, ANSI SQL compliant now.